# Mocha Testing timeout in package.json or Hardhat Config file?

Tags: hardhat, mocha

i have a conflicting question. Where should I put the mocha implementation in package.json or hardhat config file? i would assume that if i put "mocha":{ "timeout" : x} in package.json, i do not need to include it in the hardhat Config. confusing...Thx